# Use AutoMapper to Run Function to Setup Mutiple Properties Based on Other Parameters

Tags: c#, automapper

I need help to see if AutoMapper can do this.  My code has been simplified, but it gets the point across.

```
public class SourceObject
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }

}

public class DestinationObject
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
    public string Property4 { get; set; }
    public string Property5 { get; set; }
    public string Property6 { get; set; }
}

var vm = new ViewModel
{
    Objects = Mapper.Map<IList<SourceObject>, IEnumerable<DestinationObject>>(dests)
};

foreach (var destObj in vm.Objects)
{
    Utility.SetupProperties(destObj, new AnotherDependency(), destObj.Property3,
        someFlag, anotherFlag);
}
```

`Property1` to `Property3` are setup by AutoMapper currently.  I then have to loop through the list of `DestinationObjects` to setup `Property4` to `Property6` with a function, some additional flags.  I understand this might not be what AutoMapper is used for, but I really would like to avoid looping through the objects twice (once by AutoMapper, once on my own).  The static `SetupProperties` function is used in other places, so I'd like to keep it as so.  Can AutoMapper set this up?   Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Could you use [Before and After Actions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Before-and-after-map-actions) on the map between `SourceObject` and `DestinationObject`?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Like MindingData suggested, but unfortunately, I wouldn't be able to pass additional parameters into the mapping by using Before and After Actions.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what is happening inside Utility.SetupProperties, but it is possible to have more complex mapping situations with a bit of logic by using the before and after mapping actions in Automapper  : https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Before-and-after-map-actions

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
  cfg.CreateMap<SourceObject, DestinationObject>()
    .BeforeMap((src, dest) => 
    {
      //Do some work here and set properties. 
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. SetupProperties looks at the inputs and tries to determine what the rest of the properties should be. I read about the before and after mapping actions, but I don't think we can pass additional flags into it at run time, can we?

Comment: That's true. And you won't be able to do that unfortunately (As far as I know). To do so you would require a "params" input on Mapper.Map to know about additional fields it should take into account.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you could use [`AfterMap`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Before-and-after-map-actions) and capture whatever additional parameters you wanted to pass in via a closure (as in the second wiki example).  However, since you're converting between collections, I don't think there is a clean way to do that per item in this case.

I've done some digging, and I think you can use [`ITypeConverter<TSource, TDestination>`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters) to accomplish the conversion you're attempting.

I had to do some guesswork on implementation and use cases for `Utility.SetupProperties`, etc. but I think the following proof of concept Console App should demonstrate how to accomplish your custom conversion:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AutoMapper;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sourceObjects = new SourceObject[] {
                new SourceObject{Property1 = "prop 1A"},
                new SourceObject{Property2 = "Prop 2B"},
                new SourceObject{Property3 = "Prop 3C"}};

            var someFlag = true;
            var anotherFlag = false;

            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<SourceObject, DestinationObject>().ConvertUsing<CustomConverter>();
            });

            var vm = new ViewModel
            {
                Objects = Mapper.Map<IList<SourceObject>, IEnumerable<DestinationObject>>(sourceObjects, opts =>
                {
                    opts.Items.Add("AnotherDependency", new AnotherDependency { Foo = "bar" });
                    opts.Items.Add("flag1", someFlag);
                    opts.Items.Add("flag2", anotherFlag);
                })
            };

            foreach (var obj in vm.Objects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"[{obj.Property1}, {obj.Property2}, {obj.Property3}, {obj.Property4}, {obj.Property5}, {obj.Property6}]");
            }
        }
    }

    public class CustomConverter : ITypeConverter<SourceObject, DestinationObject>
    {
        public DestinationObject Convert(ResolutionContext context)
        {
            return Convert(context.SourceValue as SourceObject, context);
        }

        public DestinationObject Convert(SourceObject source, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var dest = new DestinationObject
            {
                Property1 = source?.Property1,
                Property2 = source?.Property2,
                Property3 = source?.Property3
            };

            var items = context.Options.Items;

            Utility.SetupProperties(dest,
                items["AnotherDependency"] as AnotherDependency,
                dest.Property3,
                items["flag1"] as bool? ?? false,
                items["flag2"] as bool? ?? false);

            return dest;
        }
    }

    public static class Utility
    {
        public static void SetupProperties(DestinationObject x, AnotherDependency ad, string a, bool b, bool c)
        {
            x.Property4 = ad.Foo;
            if (b || c)
            {
                x.Property5 = ad?.ToString() ?? a;
            }
            if (b && c)
            {
                x.Property6 = ad?.ToString() ?? a;
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<DestinationObject> Objects { get; set; }
    }
    public class AnotherDependency { public string Foo { get; set; } }
    public class SourceObject
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
        public string Property3 { get; set; }
    }
    public class DestinationObject
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
        public string Property3 { get; set; }
        public string Property4 { get; set; }
        public string Property5 { get; set; }
        public string Property6 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time.  I will definitely give this a try and reply back / accept!  Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Will, any luck?  Is there something I missed?

Comment: Sorry, but i haven't had a chance to try it out yet.  I will definitely come back after i do so.  Thanks again!